# Very slow response of jackson library in Java spring hibernate MVC framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jackson

I created restful web service using spring hibernate MVC which return JSON as the response. 
I am using Jackson library for this. I am creating json from a bean class and I am using hibernate approach to fetch data from MySQL server.

There are near about 20 attributes in my bean class. The problem is when there is less record say 50-100, its response time is very fast i.e. within a second, but when records are increased like 500 or more than it takes lots of time to parse from a bean to JSON i.e. up to 25-30 seconds, However, hibernate - MySQL response is still very fast.

I have deployed this web service on the local machine (i7 8 GB ram, window 7) on tomcat 7. What is going wrong with jackson?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide code where you converting the object in JSON ?

Comment: does your entity have any relations?   
did you try to return just one entity or a set? if it was a set, how did you convert it to json object? do you have any conditions/filters/criteria while reading from database? did you run the service in debug mode to see the bottleneck place?

Comment: 500 objects with 20 fields each is a large array prone to causing slow downs. I would recommend using JProfiler or VisualVM to profile execution and find where the slow down is exactly. Also, consider the possibility that the browser or the tool that you are using to view the JSON might be slow parsing and/or rendering a large response.

Comment: I agree with @Marquez: an array of 500+ entries, 20+ attributes per entry, _will_ take time to serialize anyway, whatever the serializing tool you're using in my opinion... What about pagination? That's the only scalable solution I can think about.

Comment: Hey dude, I am now in the same problem, when The RestController returns about 50 records, everything seems fine, but when returns about 500 records, everything goes so slow.  Can anyone know what's going on? JSON serialization should not be that slow.

Answer (score -2):

I would like to guess the way you convert Json back to your bean object might has performance issue.

Comment: This is basically what OP said in his question, no?

Comment: Oh, you are right, so I think he needs to refactor the code to do better converting then.